# Context EntityState and List Items

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

```
public partial class ClassCode
            {
                public long Id { get; set; }
                public long Id{ get; set; }
                public string CodeQualifier { get; set; }
                public string Code { get; set; }
                public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
                public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateEnd { get; set; }
                public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
               }


    List<ClassCode> ClassCodes = new List<ClassCode>();

 ClassCode cchc = new ClassCode();
cchc.Code ="0010";
cchc.CodeQualifier = "BF";
 ClassCode cchc1= new ClassCode();
cchc.Code ="0011";
cchc.CodeQualifier = "ABF";
ClassCodes.Add(cchc2); //Adding an item to the Collectionlist 
ClassCodes.Add(cchc1); //Adding an item to the list
```

Adding an item to the list will change the entitystate to Added.

```
var entityChangeList = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p => p.State == EntityState.Added || p.State == EntityState.Deleted || p.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

`ClassCodes.Remove(1);` This should remove one ClassCode Item from  the list and change the entitystate to Delete. Instead, it changes the state to Modified

Both adding to the list and removing from the collection of lists and  should be setting EntityState= modified.
OR 
adding an item to the list should be EntityState=Added and Removing a item from the list should be EntityState=Delete

Is this expected behavior? 
Is there anything that could be done to change the state to delete when I am removing an item from the list. This will delete the entire row in the DB on saveChanges instead of updating the current row with null values. 
I don't want to be deleting then entity. I am just deleting an entire row(entry) in the entity

```
  public partial class ParentClass
    {
   this.ClassCode= new ObservableListSource<ClassCode>();
}
public class Entities
{
 public DbSet<ParentClass> ParentClasses{ get; set; }
```

public DbSet ClassCodes{ get; set; }
    }

```
_context = new Entities();
_context.ParentClasses.Include(h=>h.ClassCode)
```

Thank you

Comment: How is this `List<ClassCode>` bound to `DbContext`?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: I have added some details on how the context knows it. Context is tracking the change but its doing a modify instead of delete.